# split environment with tex4ht

Tags: amsmath, tex4ht, htlatex

The following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{split} a &= b \\ c &= d \end{split} \]

\end{document}
```

compiles fine with pdflatex, but when I run make4ht on it, I get the following error:

```
! Package amsmath Error: \begin{split} won't work here.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \[ \begin{split} a &= b \\ c &= d \end{split}
                                                  \]
```

Is this an incompatibility of tex4ht? Is there an easy way to deal with this? I could just use `align*` in this instance, but there is a reason that I want to use `split` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\[{%
\bgroup%
  \mathdisplay@push%
  \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse%
  \mathdisplay{equation*}%
\csname st:Math\endcsname
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\]{%
\csname ed:Math\endcsname
  \endmathdisplay{equation*}%
  \mathdisplay@pop%
  \ignorespacesafterend%
\egroup
}
\makeatother
\Configure{[]}{\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It does basically the same thing as `amsmath` + the ability to use the `\Configure{[]}` command. It is used to convert the display math as picture in this example. Note that this configuration will not work for MathMl or MathJax.

[image]

For MathML, use:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Your code works well in the MathJax node without any configurations.

Comment: It's helpful to have both versions of this; I do use MathML. This is a bit off-topic, but does the mathjax method you are referring to effectively generate mathml and then run it through mathjax to generate HTML+CSS (or some other output)? I was meaning to look into how this works but didn't get the time yet.

Comment: @AlexWatson the MathJax support can either keep the math TeX code, use MathJax to render MathML, or generate HTML + CSS using MathJax node. See the `mathjaxnode` extension for `make4ht`.

Answer (score 1):

The extended help information (pressing `H`) mentions `Did you forget a preceding \begin{equation}?` This leads to a workaround: use `\begin{equation*}` instead of `\[` and similarly at the end.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split} a &= b \\ c &= d \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You're quite right. I would never have thought of this! I always thought that these were more or less synonyms, but I see that they have very different definitions in both standard latex and with tex4ht loaded.

Comment: @AlexWatson it does seem to be a bug/incompatibility of `amsmath` and `tex4ht`, in which `amsmath` expects the presence of an equation to be checkable by certain tests/booleans which are modified by `tex4ht` in such a way that the test fails. That can most likely be fixed in either package (with `tex4ht` being the more obvious candidate for fixing because that code introduces the problem). But if `equation*` is ok for you then it's probably not worth the trouble looking for a bug fix :)

Comment: `amsmath` redefines `\[` to `\begin{equation}`, but this fails with `tex4ht` configurations for display math. I know about this issue for some time, but haven't found a correct solution for all cases yet. You know, we need to support MathML, MathJax, etc. Something that works for sample cases may be broken for more complex ones.

Comment: @michal.h21 I wonder why even with `\Configure{[]}{\begin{equation*}}{\end{equation*}}{}`, there is a difference between `\[`..`\]` and `equation*` environment? Concerning your description, is it possible to delay the configurations of `displaymath` somehow `\AtBeginDocument` and then to detect whether `amsmath` is already loaded?