# tex4ebook: formatting equation, align and split

Tags: equations, align, split, tex4ebook

I realized `tex4ebook` does not format the `align` environment the same way it does to `equation`.

I would like to know how to format/to config so that `align` has the correct symbols as `equation` without damaging the format of `split`.

The original `pdf` result is shown
[image: pdf result]

The `epub` result with no `config` file. Commands `\vec` and `\hat` do not work in `align`
[image: epub result]

The `epub` result with `config` file for `align` as written in [mathdisplay in tex4ebook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472900/mathdisplay-in-tex4ebook). The equations inside `split` are not shown with its number at the right.
[image: epub result with align <code>config</code>].

And the behavior when it is stretched is very different. I would say the `split` one looks nicer.

[image: epub result with align <code>config</code> and stretched]

The `epub` result with `config` file for robust `split` as written in [split environment with tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511611/split-environment-with-tex4ht). Apparently no difference. That `config` only corrects the `\[\]` behavior.
[image: epub result with robust split config]

A MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

without config: Eq. and Eq. split = beauty. align: ugly.

with config for align: Eq. and align = beauty. Eq. split: ugly.

Eq.
\begin{equation}
    y = x^2 = x_1 = \vec{z}_1 = \underline{c}_2 = \hat{n}_3
\end{equation}

Eq. with split
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    y & = x^2 = \vec{z}_1                   \\
    a & = b^2 = \underline{c}_2 = \hat{n}_3
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Align
\begin{align}
    y & = x^2 = \vec{z}_1                   \\
    a & = b^2 = \underline{c}_2 = \hat{n}_3
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it is best to use the `pic-align,pic-equation"` options for `make4ht`. It will convert math contents to pictures. The numbered labels differ in appearance, but I was not able to fix that.